"invalid node scheme: string" while deploying docker-swarm
Here is my docker-compose.yml file to deploy traefik using docker swarm:
version: '3.3'

services:
  traefik:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.traefik == true
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$2y$$05$$password
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme.permanent=true
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.rule=Host('somedomain.com')
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.middlewares=https-redirect
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.rule=Host('somedomain.com')
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.service=api@internal
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls.certresolver=le
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.middlewares=admin-auth
        - traefik.http.services.traefik-public.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    image: traefik:v2.7
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.swarmmode=true
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=default@default.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --accesslog
      - --api
      - --log
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates
    networks:
      - traefik-public
volumes:
  traefik-public-certificates:

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true

After deploying it using docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml traefik command i finally get a service with one container running, but docker service logs traefik_traefikdisplays an error like:
traefik_traefik.1.d5yd2efpgxix@mgr    | time="2024-12-27T12:19:54Z" level=error msg="invalid node scheme: string" providerName=docker container=traefik-traefik-d5yd2efpgxixmm3ok1otpebg
I can't get rid of it. Network traefik-public is previously successfully created using  docker network create -d overlay traefik-public.
Please, could you advice me how to correct this error, or at least suggest the right direction.
I tried to remove all mentions of "container_name" or etc from compose.yml, unsuccessfully
